# Why we need First chance exception?

Tags: c#-4.0

Please briefly tell me

1. Why do we require "First chance exception"
2. What are the advantages and disadvantages of "First chance exception"
3. Where do we require this "First Chance Exception" in real time application?

Comment: If you ignore the first chance exception, you can't see the second chance exception, because it, in effect, BECOMES the first chance exception. And then you're forgetting about the Zeroeth chance exception. You might find better info here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/davidklinems/2005/07/12/what-is-a-first-chance-exception/

Comment: It is purely a debugger feature, helps to fix bugs caused by buggy try/catch code.  Very common.  Too common.  Do avoid running a "real time application" with a debugger, that makes zero sense.

Comment: Please refer [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997368(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thank you all. But using First chance exception, can we stop crashing the application in production build / environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "First chance exception" is just the name for an ordinary exception that is first caught by a debugger. If the debugger continues execution and the exception remains unhandled, it is caught again as a "second chance exception".